# How to Create an Expandable listview with section headers in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

In my application I have to include an expandable list view with section headers, I have succeeded doing them separately like list view with headers and expandable list view but when I have to do it both I am stuck,

I got three arraylist of data.
`ArrayList<String[]>` headers.
`ArrayList<String[]>` list.
`ArrayList<String[]>` child.

and I have created separate layouts for all the three. How to create this expandable list view with headers?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `addHeaderView()` method for each of the `ArrayList` of headers. This way, you can dynamically create `TextViews` or any `View` desired to each of the `ExpandableListViews`.